# How do I use pidcat?

Tags: android, python

I have installed it using `brew install pidcat` but when I type:

```
pidcat com.example.android.sunshine
```

nothing happens.

The package in my manifest is `"com.example.android.sunshine"` and `adb logcat` works completely fine. Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: does `pidcat -a` produce any output?

Comment: Yup! `pidcat: error: unrecognized arguments: -a`

Comment: what version is it? `pidcat -v`

Comment: The version is 2.0.0

Comment: Can you run it without parameters then?

Comment: Unfortunately, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Right now you have 2 options to use it.

1. For some time owner of the repo doesn't relase new versions but he still accepts fixes and features in master branch, so you can install it from master branch like this: `brew install --HEAD pidcat`. On master branch there are fixes to properly handle new format of logs from Android M. Check if you use proper version with `pidcat --verion` (you don't want 2.0.0, so if you see this version, uninstall all pidcat versions and again install master).
2. If you want to stick with version 2.0.0 (for whatever reason) use pidcat like this: `adb logcat -v brief | pidcat PACKAGE_OF_YOUR_APP`

Comment: Second option works on windows, for some reason `pidcat` doesn't work. pidcat version 2.1.0

Comment: Try Punt, does more with logcat - http://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/punt

Answer (score 0):

For wondering what is wrong I think the issue is with log level.

First of all you could run as (process all logcat events):

```
pidcat --all
```

to confirm that the app is operable. `pidcat --clear` will shorten the list.

Then you should try to alter **logging level** (V,D,I,W,E,F), the default might not capture all events from your app:

```
pidcat -l V com.evil.steal-user-money
```